# Launching Apache Spark jobs from Dev machine on Amazon EMR

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-spark

What I currently have:

- Spark cluster running on Amazon's EMR (emr-4.7.2).
- SSH tunnel to the master node using dynamic port forwarding.
- Spark application (I'm using JAVA) running locally from my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) using the following configuration:

  ```
  SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
          .setAppName("Example Spark App")
          .setMaster("local");
  ```

Question:

Is it even possible to use my cluster in client mode, while the driver application will live on my dev machine and I want to run it from my IDE? I tried the `.setMaster("yarn-client")` but no success ("unable to load yarn support").